# Use req.user instead of User.findOne when updating MongoDB sub-documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am using Passport.js for Express, which already holds the current user in the session variable `req.user`.

Yet when I try to update a MongoDB database I can only use `req.user` to identify the current user in certain cases. In others, I have to first do a root search to identify the correct user. Why?

I'm updating a database with this structure:

```
User A
   Stocks [array]
      Notes [array]
User B
   Stocks [array]
      Notes [array]
User C
   ...
```

Let's say we have already populated the database with 'stocks', and with 'notes' belonging to these 'stocks'. Now the user clicks a button to delete an existing 'note'.

This code works fine:

```
 await User.updateOne (
           { $and: [ { email: req.user.email }, { 'stocks.ticker': req.body.ticker } ]},
           { $pull: { 'stocks.$.notes': { _id: req.body.id }}}  
        )
```

This query contains both the email to identify the user, *and* the stock's ticker to identify the relevant stock. And then the note is pulled from that stock. As said, it works fine.

**But** since I already know the current user (set in Passport's `req.user` variable) I don't want to have to include the email in the query and waste resources finding the current user.

I want to reduce to this:

```
await req.user.updateOne (
           { 'stocks.ticker': req.body.ticker },
           { $pull: { 'stocks.$.notes': { _id: req.body.id }}}  
        )
```

But this does *not* work, and I don't understand why.

If I use the `req.user` variable for a simpler pull action, it does work. I.e. the following code works to pull a stock document from the user's database:

```
await req.user.updateOne (
           { $pull: { stocks: { ticker: req.body.ticker }}}
        )
```

But if I include a query before the pull action, it does not. I have tried everything I can think of to solve this. No joy.